# Can I customize CKAN backend

Tags: python, ckan

I want to implement my own api for data transfers and data results because I am using a noSql database in my storage layer. Is it possible to customize CKAN backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing CKAN's own metadata storage (PostgreSQL + Solr) would probably be a huge amount of work. The usual approach is therefore to create separate metadata entries in CKAN for the datasets in your original database. This is called *harvesting* and is usually done using the [ckanext-harvest](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest) extension.

In particular, you would [implement your own harvester](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest#the-harvesting-interface) that creates CKAN datasets and resources for the data in your NoSQL database. The resources you create in your harvester can link back to the NoSQL database, so that the data itself is not duplicated.